# Teradata SQL Assistant Date Inserts

Tags: teradata

Context is Teradata SQL Assistant

Successfully created the following table:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE RSN_WEEKLY_TMP, NO LOG
(
EXPLICIT_DATE DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY'
)
PRIMARY INDEX (EXPLICIT_DATE)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

1) The following INSERT works successfully:

```
INSERT INTO JOCOOPER.RSN_WEEKLY_TMP (EXPLICIT_DATE) VALUES (CURRENT_DATE);
```

2) The following INSERT does not work and returns with Error:INSERT Failed [26665] Invalid date.

```
INSERT INTO JOCOOPER.RSN_WEEKLY_TMP (EXPLICIT_DATE) VALUES (02/02/2016);
```

3) However, if I use a string 'date value' and CAST it as a Date it works.

```
INSERT INTO JOCOOPER.RSN_WEEKLY_TMP (EXPLICIT_DATE) VALUES (CAST('02/03/2016' AS DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY') );
```

I need to know how to make example #2 work? Please Advise?

Answer (score 1):

`02/02/2016` is an INTEGER calculation, dividing 2 by 2 by 2016, results in zero, of course this is not a valid date.

`CAST('02/03/2016' AS DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY')` works because it tells the parser how to convert the string to a DATE.

The only recommended (and the shortest) way is a Standard SQL DATE literal:

```
DATE '2016-02-03'
```

You never need to think about formats because there's only one: `YYYY-MM-DD`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this format works too

```
insert into table_name (datecol) select '2015/12/31';
```

In your example:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE RSN_WEEKLY_TMP, NO LOG
(
--EXPLICIT_DATE DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY'
EXPLICIT_DATE DATE
)
PRIMARY INDEX (EXPLICIT_DATE)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO JOCOOPER.RSN_WEEKLY_TMP (EXPLICIT_DATE) select '2016/02/02';
```